# Stealing SSL Session Id can cause any harm?

Tags: tls

In SSL handshake, server shares the SessionId in Server Hello message and since there is no encryption yet, so anyone can capture this ?

Is it risky ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not risky.

The session is in ServerHello references a previously established TLS session which can be chosen to resume by the client.

This makes it possible to leave out otherwise repeated handshakes, but with just the session id, an attacker cannot do much.

Even if the attacker previously witnessed the handshake that is now skipped, they would know the configuration parameters (as they are the same) of the session - but not the ephemeral keys that got exchanged during the last handshake, as their transmission was secure in the first place (assuming that TLS was used in the right version and with the right configuration).

The misunderstanding might come from the multiple use of „session“: in TLS, there are sessions - and in HTTP(S), there are sessions as well, sometimes. The session id in the ServerHello is not an HTTP(S) session cookie, though. They are different things altogether.

A TLS session has nothing to do with the session you may know from “http session hijacking”.

Comment: So what i understand is that any one can steal the session id.

But since s/he won't have the symmetric key exchanged s/he can't do any harm? Right ?

Comment: Right. They merely are able to resume a session for which they have no key and know the used cipher - which wouldn’t bring any benefit for reasonably secure ciphers.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.digicert.com/ssl-cryptography.htm, SSL(Secure Sockets Layer) uses both symmetric and asymmetric encryption and I want to answer your question by considering above mentioned point.

Consider a scenario where client A wants to communicate with a server B and a hacker C is eavesdropping on the communication link.Client A sends HELLO message to the server B and server B replies with Server HELLO message. Basically, HELLO messages contain session specific data,version number and cipher settings. Once these messages gets shared, Server B and Client A authenticates each other using client certificate and server digital certificate respectively. Only server digital certificate provides encryption facility in initial connection process so all the requests from clients gets encrypted using server public key obtained after verifying of digital certificate using the process called chain of trust.

And up until now, hacker C knows content of the HELLO messages that were exchanged during initial connection setup as they were unencrypted.
Now Client A's browser generates a random symmetric key using session-data as one of its parameters, which will be used by server and client to encrypt the future exchanged messages, and sends that key in encrypted form using server B' public key to encrypt it, because of which hacker C cannot read the data as its encrypted and can only be decrypted by server's private key.

After symmetric key gets to the server B, B decrypts it using its private key. Now both have symmetric key which can be used to form a encrypted tunnel and no one can decrypt the messages encrypted using common symmetric key which is kept private by client A and server B. Now whenever server or client has to send messages to each other they use this symmetric key, which is unique to their session, to encrypt the messages which no-one can read except them, unless someone somehow get access to this private symmetric key.

Now if we consider hacker in this scenario, he was only able to read HELLO messages but was not able to get his hand on symmetric key as it was encrypted when sent to server.So even if he was able to get session specific data from the HELLO messages he cannot do anything about it as for to be able to read the messages exchanged between the server and client , he needs that symmetric key used for encryption to decrypt the messages and that symmetric key was only exchanged with the server in encrypted form because of its public key which no one else can read except the server.

What a hacker might think to do is, send his own generated symmetric key and capture the client encrypted symmetric key in middle and prevent it from reaching the server, after stealing the session specific data from HELLO messages, Following which the server uses hacker's symmetric key.This will lead to server responses being encrypted with hacker's symmetric key and not decryptable at client's end so communication between client and server will fail, and also when the client will try to encrypt his or her messages the server will not be able to decrypt that message as the server has not received that particular client symmetric key which will also lead to failure in communication and restrict further message exchange.

So in conclusion, hacker C cannot do anything even after reading the session specific data from the unencrypted HELLO messages exchanged between the client A and the server B.